# Custom input formatter in C# / ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have created a custom input formatter in C# and I'm trying to register it like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers(options =>
        {
            options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new CSPReportInputFormatter ());
        });
}

public class CSPReportInputFormatter : TextInputFormatter
{
    public CSPReportInputFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/csp-report"));
        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.UTF8);
    }

    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        using var reader = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body);
        string responseString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContentSecurityPolicyRequest>(responseString);

        return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(data);
    }
}
```

When I use `AddControllers` this mediatype is getting applied to all controllers available at the global level. I just want to apply to one particular controller and action method.

How can I do that?

Comment: Is your question about Input or Output? Why are you inserting it before all other formatters (thus making it default)? Have you set the supported media types on the formatter?

Comment: Even with  `.Insert(0` this wouldn't be the default if you only used Excel Mime types in  `SupportedMediaTypes.Add`. Please post the `ExcelOutputFormatter`, or at least the code where you specify the supported media types. The correct MIME type for Excel is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Comment: Sorry, for confusion i have updated my question

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In my testing, if no `Accept` header is passed by the client, it does indeed act as the default. Please test this for yourself. Edit: I note that the question has since been updated to use `.InputFormatters` rather than `.OutputFormatters`. My comment is regarding output formatters.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama my point was that we didn't have enough information and *if used properly* the formatter shouldn't interfere. The question changed a lot now, but using `Add` instead of `Insert(0,` should fix things. `SupportedMediaTypes` is configured which means the *request* doesn't have the correct content type. I suspect the next question will be "why isn't my formatter used"